# Comparing Records in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**I have a redshift table in this format:**

```
| id | email | start_dt | end_dt |
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:|
| 123 | abc@gmail.com | 1900-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
| 123 | abc@gmail.com | 2018-01-02 | 2019-01-01 |
| 123 | xyz@yahoo.com | 2019-01-02 | 2020-01-01 |
| 123 | abc@gmail.com | 2020-01-02 | 9999-01-01 |
```

**And I am expecting a table in this format**

```
| id | email | start_dt | end_dt |
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:|
| 123 | abc@gmail.com | 1900-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
| 123 | xyz@yahoo.com | 2019-01-02 | 2020-01-01 |
| 123 | abc@gmail.com | 2020-01-02 | 9999-01-01 |
```

I thought to use Group By but then I will get only 2 rows. I believe I need recursive CTE but not sure how to use it.

Here is my attempted code:

```
select id, email, min(start_dt), max(end_dt)
from table
group by id, email;
```

Comment: Search for “gaps and islands sql” in SO and you will find a number of examples

Answer (score 0):

Had to do a running sum to identify the groups:

```
with tmp as (
select member_id, member_email, start_dtts, end_dtts
, lag(member_email) over(partition by member_id order by start_dtts) as prev_email
from operational_model_v_200.member_h
where member_id = '634'
)

select member_id, member_email, grp, min(start_dtts), max(end_dtts)
from (
        select *
        , sum(start_ind) over(partition by member_id order by start_dtts rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
                from (
                select *
                , case when prev_email is null or prev_email <> member_email then 1 else 0 end as start_ind
                --, sum(case when prev_start >= start_dtts then 0 else 1 end) over(order by rn) as id
                from tmp
                )
)
group by member_id, member_email, grp
--        order by start_dtts
```